# Remove end of line equals signs (=) from HTML code stored in buffer?

Tags: html

I am trying to store HTML code in a buffer variable (it's being read in from the body of an [IMAP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap) request). However, every line that runs too long gets interrupted by an equals sign. For example, the buffer variable is

```
<span class=3D"m_-124141435523464643mcnPreviewText" style=3D"display=
:none;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;o=
verflow:hidden">Title</span>
```

When I want it to be:

```
<span class=3D"m_-124141435523464643mcnPreviewText" style=3D"display
:none;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;o
verflow:hidden">Title</span>
```

How do I store it without the equals sign?

Comment: Why does your expected result still have `3D` after the legitimate `=` signs? Do you really still want to keep the line breaks? `o`⟨linebreak⟩`verflow` won’t work in a `style` attribute.

Comment: No, I don't want to keep any of the line breaks. Thanks for the work below, I am going to try it today. I'm not sure what the 3D is - haven't gotten that far yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the variable is named as `buf`, here you go:

```js
const buf = Buffer.from("request buffer") // NOTE: THIS IS THE BUFFER RETURNED FROM THE IMAP REQUEST
const bufStr = buf.toString();
const bufStrEqualsStripped = bufStr.split('\n').map(str => str.replace(/=$/, "")).join('\n');
```

If you don't want to keep the new line as well, just change the argument to the `join` method from `\n` to `''` (empty string).

Alternatively, you can use `replaceAll` function on a string, which is very, very new(ES2021).

Comment: Alternatively, use [`bufStr.replace(/=$/gm, "");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline).

Comment: Thank you, another comment clued me in that I could use the 'quoted-printable' package earlier on to solve this more smoothly but this works too!